# If you flush the content (ob_flush) of an AJAX request, the content will get loaded?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, output-buffering

I mean... Let's that we just make an AJAX request and inser the result inside a div#result..

In the backend the script use **ob_flush()** to send the header but not terminate the request until it's terminated (with **exit** or **ob_flush_end**)

The content will be loaded into the #result only when the request terminate (**exit** or **ob_flush_end**) or it'll be loaded every time the script send the header by **ob_flush**?

**Update:**

I'll use [jQuery load()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback) to make the request & PHP to answer it

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no ob_end.  There is however, ob_end_flush and ob_end_clean, neither of which will "terminate the request"; they merely turn off output buffering.

Comment: @bish - Thank's.. Corrected :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, content will be returned, but the XHR object's readyState will not be set to 4, so if you are relying on that to update your div (which most JS libraries' AJAX auto updaters do), you won't see it automatically.

Comment: I don't think so. I have a feeling that what you want here is not AJAX but COMET (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).

Comment: Then give this a try... http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php#71172